# How complex can I make my Model in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I think I might have overbuilt the model for my MVC 5 page.

The model is called **RegionalDealerships** (plural) and it is a collection of **RegioalDealership** items (singular). Further, each of these individual dealerships contains a collection of **ModelStock**.

### Model (in 3 parts)

```cs
namespace CCNRebuild.Models
{
    // Part 1
    public class ModelStock
    {
        private string series;

        public ModelStock(string modelName)
        {
            Name = modelName;
            Series = string.Empty;
            Rolling12Count = 0;
            InventoryCount = 0;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Series
        {
            get
            {
                switch (series)
                {
                    case "1":
                        return "10";
                    case "A":
                        return "A";
                    case "D":
                        return "OUTBOARD";
                    case "R":
                        return "BOWRIDER";
                    case "W":
                        return "SURF";
                    default:
                        return series;
                }
            }
            set { series = value; }
        }

        public int Rolling12Count { get; set; }

        public int InventoryCount { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name} {Series}: AFS: {InventoryCount}; R12: {Rolling12Count}";
        }
    }
```

```cs
    // Part 2
    public class RegionalDealership : List<ModelStock>
    {

        public RegionalDealership()
        {
            Name = "";
            Number = "";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Number { get; set; }

        public int Rolling12Total
        {
            get
            {
                var total = 0;
                foreach (var model in this)
                {
                    total += model.Rolling12Count;
                }
                return total;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public int InventoryTotal
        {
            get
            {
                var total = 0;
                foreach (var model in this)
                {
                    total += model.InventoryCount;
                }
                return total;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name} ({Number}) AFS: {InventoryTotal}; R12: {Rolling12Total}";
        }

    }
```

```cs
    // Part 3
    public class RegionalDealerships : List<RegionalDealership>
    {
        public RegionalDealerships()
        {
            Name = string.Empty;
            Region = string.Empty;
            Ready = false;
            Regions = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "", Value = "All" },
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "All Regions", Value = "All" }
            };
        }

        public List<string> GetSeries()
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            foreach (var dealership in this)
            {
                foreach (var model in dealership)
                {
                    var item = model.Series;
                    if (!result.Contains(item))
                    {
                        result.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            result.Sort();
            return result;
        }

        public List<ModelStock> GetModels(string series = null)
        {
            var result = new List<ModelStock>();
            foreach (var dealership in this)
            {
                foreach (var model in dealership.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(series) || x.Series == series))
                {
                    result.Add((ModelStock)model);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Ready { get; set; }

        public string StartDate { get; set; }

        public string EndDate { get; set; }

        public int InventoryTotal
        {
            get
            {
                var count = 0;
                foreach(var dealership in this)
                {
                    count += dealership.InventoryTotal;
                }
                return count;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public string Region { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Regions { get; set; }

        public int Rolling12Total
        {
            get
            {
                var count = 0;
                foreach (var dealership in this)
                {
                    count += dealership.Rolling12Total;
                }
                return count;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name} AFS: {InventoryTotal}; R12: {Rolling12Total}";
        }
    }

}
```

### View

```html
@model CCNRebuild.Models.RegionalDealerships
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegionalAvailability", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <label>
        Region:@Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.Region,
        Model.Regions)
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
@if (Model.Ready)
{
  // lots more code
```

### Controller

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> RegionalAvailability()
{
    var model = new RegionalDealerships();
    var sql = $"SELECT DISTINCT RGNAMEM FROM REGIONPF WHERE RGRCID<>'X' ORDER BY RGNAMEM ASC WITH UR";
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, new OleDbConnection(m_conn)))
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var disrgn = $"{reader[0]}";
                model.Regions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = disrgn, Value = disrgn });
            }
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RegionalAvailability(RegionalDealerships model)
{
    model = RetailActivityModelData.RegionalAvailability(model, ViewBag.Library);
    return View("Admin", model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<RegionalDealerships> RegionalAvailabilityAsync(string region)
{
    var model = await RetailActivityModelData.RegionalAvailabilityAsync(region, ViewBag.Library);
    return View("Admin", model);
}
```

The page will load with the initial `public async Task<ActionResult> RegionalAvailability()` method. It populates the `Html.DropDownList`.

**Submit** will call the `public ActionResult RegionalAvailability(RegionalDealerships model)` method, but the `model` parameter is always `null`.

I cannot get the `public async Task<RegionalDealerships> RegionalAvailabilityAsync(string region)` to call at all, even if I change the name in the **View**.

I tried searching for rules to use with creating an ASP.NET MVC Model, but searching for that only returned **required field validator** data.

Are there parts of the Model that I cannot use? Are there parts that need to be rewritten?